# Making an object align with a vector

Tags: matrices

[image: Object I want to align]

How do i get the rotation matrix required (a 4 by 4 one) to Rotate an object such that it faces a vector
(that is the object's local y axis points towards the vector)

Comment: A $4 \times 4$ rotation matrix? Are you working in $\Bbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @user No: they're working in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations)

Comment: @S It is unclear what you mean by "faces a vector" or "points towards the vector".

Comment: Yes I am using homogeneous coordinates as I am using opengl

Comment: I mean points towards the vector

Comment: By facing the vector I mean that the line representing the vector and the object's y axis coincides

Comment: There’s an infinite number of such rotations. Do you have any other criteria or constraints? [Here’s](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624557/265466) a way to construct one of them. If you do some searching on this site, you’ll find quite a few other questions like yours.